# HTML5 Canvas - how to zoom in the pixels?

Tags: javascript, html, canvas

How would one zoom in a Canvas to see the pixels? Currently when I try to use the scale() function the image is always antialiased.

The property `mozImageSmoothingEnabled` seems to work, but it's only for Firefox.

Answer (score 4):

As far as I know any rescaling done by the browser will result in a smooth interpolation.

So as long as you want to do this with JS you will have to let JS do all the work. This means either finding a nice library or writing a function yourself. It could look like this. But I hope it's possible to make it faster. As it's one of the simplest scaling algorithms there are probably many people who thought up improvements to do it even faster.

```
function resize(ctx, sx, sy, sw, sh, tx, ty, tw, th) {
    var source = ctx.getImageData(sx, sy, sw, sh);
    var sdata = source.data;

    var target = ctx.createImageData(tw, th);
    var tdata = target.data;

    var mapx = [];
    var ratiox = sw / tw, px = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < tw; ++i) {
        mapx[i] = 4 * Math.floor(px);
        px += ratiox;
    }

    var mapy = [];
    var ratioy = sh / th, py = 0;
    for (var i = 0; i < th; ++i) {
        mapy[i] = 4 * sw * Math.floor(py);
        py += ratioy;
    }

    var tp = 0;
    for (py = 0; py < th; ++py) {
        for (px = 0; px < tw; ++px) {
            var sp = mapx[px] + mapy[py];
            tdata[tp++] = sdata[sp++];
            tdata[tp++] = sdata[sp++];
            tdata[tp++] = sdata[sp++];
            tdata[tp++] = sdata[sp++];
        }
    }

    ctx.putImageData(target, tx, ty);
}
```

This function would take the rectangle of size (sw,sh) at (sx,sy), resize it to (tw,th) and draw it at (tx,ty).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know the antialiasing behavior is not defined in the spec and will depend on the browser.

One thing you could try is if you set the canvas's width/height with CSS into for example 300x300 and then give the canvas width and height attributes of 150 and 150, it will appear "zoomed in" by 200%. I'm not sure whether this will trigger the antialiasing, but do give it a shot.

Comment: Trigger AA too, there's a chrome issue... with little progress:  http://code.google.com/p/chromium/issues/detail?id=1502